# $SU(2)$ vs. $SO(3)$ transformation, spinor rotation and measurement

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, spinors, observables, quantum-measurements

Is it possible to *measure* the effects of $SU(2)$ rotations acting on spinor wave functions $\psi$ in the fundamental representation? That means, is it possible to extract information that distinguishes $SU(2)$ from $SO(3)$ rotations?

These are basically **two questions**:

1. How would an observable, a matrix element … look like mathematically?
2. What would be an appropriate experimental setup?

In principle the effects of the $SU(2)$ rotations can be calculated quite easily, but it is not clear to me how they can be measured. The following is just a collection of ideas.

Regarding (1) a first idea – but there may be others – goes into the direction of the Aharonov-Bohm effect, but including a non-vanishing, *constant* magnetic field. The reason is that an $SU(2)$ rotation

$$ U_\alpha = e^{-i \sigma_k\alpha_k /2} $$

has the same structure as one of the interaction terms

$$ H_\text{int} \sim \sigma_k B_k $$

for a spinor coupled to a constant magnetic field $B$ in the Pauli-equation, when promoted to the time evolution operator

$$ U(t) = e^{-iHt} = e^{-iH_At} \otimes e^{-i \sigma_k\alpha_k /2} $$

where the first exponential depending on the vector potential $A$ acts on position space only, the second one depending on the magnetic field $B$ acts on spin space only, and where I used $\alpha_k \sim B_k \, t$.

If we are able to let an appropriate interaction rotate the spin in just one one of two components of a spinor wave function

$$ \psi_0 = \psi_{0,1} + \psi_{0,2} $$

$$ \psi(t) = U_{B=0}(t) \, \psi_{0,1} + U_{B \neq 0}(t) \, \psi_{0,2} $$

and to measure the interference pattern of $|\psi(t)|^2$ that may demonstrate the effect created by the $SU(2)$ rotation.

Splitting the wave functions into position and spin part

$$ \psi_\chi(r) = u(r) \otimes \chi $$

and using $B$ in y-direction we get

$$ |\psi|^2 = |u_1|^2 + |u_2|^2 + (u_1^\ast u_2 + u_2^\ast u_1 ) \, \cos(\alpha /2) $$

where the cosine is caused by the $SU(2)$ rotation, $\alpha \sim B \, t$.

As said, this is just an idea, there may be others to address question (1).

Regarding an *experiment* (2) to measure the effects derived from the idea (1) I see several problems: The idea looks feasible only in the case of a constant magnetic field $B = \text{const}$. The effect of the magnetic field $B$ rotating the spin part $\chi$ is mixed with the interaction caused by the vector potential $A$ acting on the position space wave function $u$; therefore, it is not clear how to extract the sole effect of the $SU(2)$ rotation. The ansatz with the interference of two components requires us to confine $B$ to a spatial region, such that only one component is affected by the rotation, whereas the other component does not feel any interaction with $B$ (but still with $A$).

Comment: A few things in this question confuse me. The matrices from $SU(2)$ act on vectors from $\mathbb C^2$ thereby changing more than just the phase. The Lie algebra of $SU(2)$ is generated by the (hermitian) Pauli matrices that measure spin, as we know. The observable that measures if a state is $\psi$ is the projection $|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|$. See [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/773352/physical-interpretation-of-the-inner-product-between-two-quantum-states/773356#773356).

Comment: Sorry for  the confusion. In the end I am interested in the difference of SU(2) vs. SU(3) rotations. So I would like to measure the *difference* of the effects of two rotations $U_1, U_2 \in \text{SU(2)}$ acting on a spinor in the fundamental representation of SU(2), which are mapped to the *same* $U \in \text{SO(3)}$.

Comment: The observable you are proposing is not sufficient b/c it is bilinear and therefore not able to detect any phase.

Comment: Anyway, I am more interested in the experimental setup. Calculating effects of the phase mathematically is not the problem.

Comment: Before we get to $SU(2)$ vs. $SO(3)$ let me ask again about phase. [This answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/773451/304394) in the post I linked earlier says imho correctly that phase has no direct physical meaning and that states which just differ by a phase are identical. Why do you want to measure that?

Comment: But phase differences *can* be measured. For a $2\pi$ rotation the matrix exponential is just a phase, namely $U(2\pi) = -1$. The rotation acting only on the B component of the wave function  will create interference terms. I am not questioning the math, I am looking for an experiment that performs such a rotation and measures the resulting interference patterns.

Comment: Please be more specific what you mean by "phase difference". Sure: in the double slit experiment a phase difference causes interference on the screen. This is however *not* contradicting to what I said earlier: states don't change under a multiplication with a global phase.

Comment: Kurz please look at my post. There’s the math and the hint re the Aharonov-Bohm effect. What is missing? It is clear how to *calculate* that SU(2) rotation. But is there an *experiment*?

Comment: A lot of context and clarity is missing. If you want to study the Aharonov-Bohm effect (thanks for finally mentioning it) I recommend [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/773444/304394) and further references.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Has The Aharonov-Bohm Effect Been Experimentally Proven?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/53442/has-the-aharonov-bohm-effect-been-experimentally-proven)

Comment: I tried to clarify: I want to measure the effects of SU(2) rotations acting on spinors. The Aharonov-Bohm effect is not the answer b/c my idea works only on case of a *non-vanishing* magnetic field whereas the Aharonov-Bohm effect demonstrates effects with *vanishing* magnetic field. But it could be used as a starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us analyze a more general setup. Suppose you have two spins, one has spin-$S_1$ and the other has spin-$S_2$. No restriction on $S_1$ or $S_2$. We can then consider any state in the two-spin Hilbert space. To be explicit, we can expand them in the $S^z$ eigenbasis:

$|\psi\rangle=\sum_{m_1,m_2}c_{m_1m_2}|m_1m_2\rangle$

Now we apply $2\pi$ rotation to just one of the spin, say the first spin. Let us assume that this can be done, without worrying about practical issues It transforms $|\psi\rangle$ in the following way:

$|\psi\rangle\rightarrow \sum_{m_1,m_2}c_{m_1m_2}(-1)^{2S_1}|m_1m_2\rangle=(-1)^{2S_1}|\psi\rangle$

Still just an overall phase, which is not observable.

Apparently, the same is true even when we have more spins.

The only way out is that somehow, you can have a "spin" whose Hilbert space is a direct sum of both half-integer spin and integer spin. However, if we are only allowed to build things out of tensor products of spin-$1/2$'s (or for that matter, any spin-$S$), we will never get such direct sum. This is the superselection rule.

Comment: Thanks you. That’s clear.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't checked all details and referenced papers, but that goes into the right direction:

[4π-Periodicity of the spinor wave function under space rotation](https://www.academia.edu/79120272/4%CF%80_Periodicity_of_the_spinor_wave_function_under_space_rotation)

We report the results of an experiment which observed the 4π-symmetry of the neutron wave function under space rotation by the use of a slowly rotating magnetic field which trapped the precessing neutron spin and turned it in space.